# python getoutput() equivalent in subprocess

Tags: python, shell, command, subprocess

I want to get the output from some shell commands like `ls` or `df` in a python script. I see that `commands.getoutput('ls')` is deprecated but `subprocess.call('ls')` will only get me the return code.

I'll hope there is some simple solution.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use **subprocess.Popen**:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
print(out)
```

Note that communicate blocks until the process terminates. You could use **process.stdout.readline()** if you need the output before it terminates. For more information see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module).

Comment: The correct current doc link for the Python 2.7 version of `subprocess` examples is:  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module ; for Python 3.2, http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module

Comment: You probably need to replace the subprocess.communicate() with process.communicate() - you may also need the subprocess exit code by doing process.returncode

Comment: I didn't notice that I had written subprocess instead of process. Fixed.

Comment: what types are out and err? are they regular strings or are they arrays or dictionaries?

Comment: Works fine for `out` but `err` will be uninitialized and the error output printed to the screen. You'll have to specify `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` in addition to `stdout` to get the standard error.

Comment: What type is "out"? It looks like it's an object of some type because I cannot write it to a file like it's a string `subprocess.Popen(["echo", out, ">>", "/home/ec2-user/output_test.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 57):

For Python >= 2.7, use `subprocess.check_output()`.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Technically, it should be `subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)`.

Comment: What is the difference shell True or False?

Comment: I think it enables "shell specific features" like file globbing, piping etc...

Comment: @RickyWilson commands baked into the shell like 'dir' (or 'ls') will give you an error and not be found unless you pass in shell=True, along with the other shell-specific features like piping as stated above.  Otherwise the subprocess cmd list should be a valid filepath and its arguments.  Also when shell=True you may incur a max string length of the command allowed, depending on platform, whereas shell=False would allow a longer command to be digested than a shell would normally allow to be typed in manually.

Answer (score 12):

To catch errors with `subprocess.check_output()`, you can use `CalledProcessError`. If you want to use the output as string, decode it from the bytecode.

```
# \return String of the output, stripped from whitespace at right side; or None on failure.
def runls():
    import subprocess
    try:
        byteOutput = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-a'], timeout=2)
        return byteOutput.decode('UTF-8').rstrip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error in ls -a:\n", e.output)
        return None
```