# "make install" with Python

Tags: python, bash, makefile

I'm converting a Bash script to Python. I have been looking for a replacement for the "make install" - line. Is there any?

```
print "Installing from the sources"
urllib.urlretrieve("http://"+backupserver+"/backup-manager.tar.gz","backup-manager.tar.gz")
tar = tarfile.open("backup-manager.tar.gz", "r:gz")
tar.extractall()    
tar.close() 
os.chdir("Backup-Manager-0.7.10")
make install
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['make', 'install'])
```

Should do the trick.

If you want the output look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657690/python-getoutput-equivalent-in-subprocess)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried with check_call, didn't even consider this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

or else
`import os
os.system("make install")`

Some information about [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Oh, you could do that too? I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to run other programs from Python.