# Running bash commands in Python: os vs subprocess?

Tags: python, bash

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4256107/756329) in which the asker is having a specific problem with running bash in Python using code like this:

```
os.system(bashCommand)
```

The top two answers simply say: "use `subprocess`" (instead of `os.system`), and give a quick code example.

What is the proper way to run bash commands with Python and why? To me, it seems that `os.system` is a good option, being designed for this type of thing, and it is simply a fluke that the asker of the other question couldn't accomplish correct functionality with that package. But, is it "the true Pythonic way" to use `subprocess`? Or in other words, what is the difference between `os.system` and `subprocess`?

Comment: A better duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @JosphHansen It's worth noting that the `system()` function in C -- which `os.system()` wraps without changes -- is very, *very* old: It was designed back before security concerns were a thing, for example, so there wasn't any attention paid to keeping data out-of-band from code. It's not a good API in *any* language if one is concerned about handling hostile data safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subprocess gives you much more control over what's going on.

For example, you can redirect output to pipe it to your program like that:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

(Example from [python getoutput() equivalent in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657690/python-getoutput-equivalent-in-subprocess))

If you used `system()` you'd have to do redirection of input, saving it to file and weird things like that.

---

In documentation for `os.system` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) it is said that:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes.