# Bizarre behaviour of cgi python script

Tags: python, apache, cgi

```
#!/bin/python 

import os

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
os.system("echo a")
```

When running this on apache server it says `Error message: malformed header from script 'test.py': Bad header: a`. However if i replace `os.system("echo a")` by `print("a")` it works fine. On command line the output of both seems identical... What is happening here?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255498/python-cgi-os-system-causing-malformed-header.