# Problem printing popen stdout from subprocess

Tags: python, popen, python-2.6, fdopen

i need put the output command to a variable.
I was trying this:

```
import os
import subprocess

output = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print (output.stdout)

output.terminate()
```

but i get

```
'open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0xb76db5a0>'
```

what is the problem ? It's okay ?

i use python 2.6.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python getoutput() equivalent in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657690/python-getoutput-equivalent-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output.stdout` is a file object. You can use the `read` method of the file object to get the content of the output:

```
print(output.stdout.read())
```

or you can use the [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method instead:

```
stdout, stderr = output.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Comment: Excuse me! I'm newbie in it.