# /bin/sh: 1: [: missing ]

Tags: python, linux

I'm making a python script that will automatically check if nmap is installed on a computer and then proceed to run nmap. One problem I have is when it is run it comes back with `/bin/sh: 1: [: missing ]` and I was also wondering how one would pipe the output of a terminal back into my program. Let's say I run `hostname -I` how can I copy the output and assign it a variable name in my script. thanks the code is below

```
import os
import subprocess
def isInstalled(name):
    cmd = """ if ! [ -x "$#(command -v """ + name + """)" ]; then
      echo '0'
      exit 0
    fi"""
    ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).strip()
    if ret == b'0':
        return False
    return True

if isInstalled('nmap'):
print("Nmap is installed")

else:
    print("nmap is uninstalled since quite mode is active auto install will")
```

Comment: This is not a linux problem, but a shell problem: please adjust tags.

Comment: Your code really should not give this error. However, with a tiny modification it will: if you write `[ -x "$#(command -v """ + name + """)"]; then` (without a space between `)"` and `]`) then it will give this error. Can you please copy-paste your code from this question into a new file and double check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your default shell is `sh` that doesn't have [test utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix)) available, so try to specify bash shebang `#!/bin/bash` in script to be composed:

```
def isInstalled(name):
    cmd = """#!/bin/bash
    if ! [ -x "$#(command -v """ + name + """)" ]; then
      echo '0'
      exit 0
    fi"""
    ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).strip()
    if ret == b'0':
        return False
    return True
```

Or you can use [double brackets](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash) for if-else statement in bash:

```
if [[ some expression ]]
then
    some code
fi
```

Comment: under return True I would put "if isInstalled('nmap'): " right?

Comment: It's great that this was accepted, but adding a shebang in this case does not matter and will not make the script run with Bash. I suspect OP simply reformatted the code to make it prettier for posting, and unintentionally inserted a missing space before the `]` thereby fixing the original error

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your indentation and the blank line between print and else.

Take into account this:

> Tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces such
>   that the total number of characters up to and including the
>   replacement is a multiple of eight (this is intended to be the same
>   rule as used by Unix). The total number of spaces preceding the first
>   non-blank character then determines the line’s indentation.
>   Indentation cannot be split over multiple physical lines using
>   backslashes; the whitespace up to the first backslash determines the
>   indentation.

Change your code to this:

```
if isInstalled('nmap'):
    print("Nmap is installed")
else:
    print("nmap is uninstalled since quite mode is active auto install will")
```

Regarding to your second question, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657718/3589567