# The If else statement for Python's subprocess doesn't seem to work

Tags: python

I created a simple script to locate a user on the local machine. Despite entering any characters in the input box, the answer remains the same. I am grateful for any assistance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

user = input("Enter username : ")

result = subprocess.getoutput("getent passwd" + user)
if result:
 print(("found "+user+" user in this system."))
else:
 print((""+user+" is not found..."))
```

Comment: Are you missing a space when concatenating the command and username?

Comment: see. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657690/python-getoutput-equivalent-in-subprocess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is because in the concatination, it should be a space that separates the `database` and the `key`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

user = input("Enter username : ")

result = subprocess.getoutput("getent passwd " + user) #added space after 'passwd'
if result:
 print(("found "+user+" user in this system."))
else:
 print((""+user+" is not found..."))
```

also, the double parentheses are uneccessary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

user = input("Enter username : ")

result = subprocess.getoutput("getent passwd " + user) #added space after 'passwd'
if result:
 print("found "+user+" user in this system.")
else:
 print(user+" is not found...")
```

Comment: yes, but the getoutput function doesn't return True or False, thats just wrong

Comment: After resolving the space issue, it is working fine now. I really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Thanks man, could you mark it as an answer, it could help others.

Comment: It's really strange, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: $ ./find_user.py
Please enter user name : fdjslfjadsl;fjasdl
found fdjslfjadsl;fjasdl user in this system.

Comment: this is because you are separating the command with the `;`